# bash script to interact over several files

Tags: bash, loops, sed, awk

I need to perform the following tasks. These are included in a bash script.

1) Read from a file such as the one below, and for all the lines that have both the vars
var1="AB" and var2="14003" I need to catch the substring from col 4 with a len of 8, say in var3,(an array, prob. or in a loop, and then delete those lines.

```
2 *563587992014-01-26      2014-01-26T09:45:53     AB  14003 5         3.60
2  563589242014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:13     AB  14003 6         4.80
2  563589252014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:20     TC  14002 2         5.50
2  563589272014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:34     FF  14002 3         3.30
```

matching fields marked with *
2) Then I need to go thru the collected substrings and to open another file like the one below and to delete all lines that the substring(4,8) matches the previous collected in var3

```
    56370388   1   1.000    95         0.80Double Coffe
   *56358799   1   1.000    94         0.40Milk‚
   *56358799   2   1.000    94         0.40Coffe‚
    56370388   1   1.000    97         0.40Descafe
```

I was thinking maybe in a nested loop, using awk and sed. But inputs would be appreciated :)

Comment: much of the data in your sample output doesn't seem to be in your sample input. A good Q on S.O. will have 1. given this sample input, 2. example sample output. 3. Stack Overflow isnt meant to be a source for free programming, so you're expected to include in your question the your current code, 4. your current output and 5. your thoughts about why it isn't working ;-) OK?!? ;-).  Also know you can use the `{}` tool at the top left of the input box show code formatting. Good luck.

Comment: Why is there only a star at the first row in the top file? Shouldn't there be a star also at the second row? (The second row seems to also match `var1` and `var2`..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start: Try the following bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

var1="AB"
var2="14003"

awk -vv1="$var1" -vv2="$var2" '    
    NR==FNR {
        if ($4==v1 && $5==v2) {
            s=substr($0,4,8)
            a[s]++
        }
        next
    }
    !($1 in a) {
        print
    }' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
56370388   1   1.000    95         0.80Double Coffe
56370388   1   1.000    97         0.40Descafe
```

Comment: thank you Håkon Hægland, but it does not work in my system.
if I understand, the script compares the fourth position of each line of file1 against vv1 and vv2, and if they match, it generates a substring assigned to variable s. Pardon my ignorance, but if there is a NEXT, shouldn't be also a FOR !?

Comment: @PedroCaldeira The `next` statement is not related to `for` in `awk`. `next` is used to process the next input record, skipping all remaining rules in the `awk` program.. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Next-Statement

Comment: Yes, I get /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

strange, first time I see this running a bash script in this computer

Comment: @PedroCaldeira Try to remove everything from the script. Except for the top line.. Do you still get an error?

Comment: Try type `which bash`

Comment: What is the name of the script?

Comment: O named it test (no extension)

Comment: Ok:) For the modified script (with only a single line), try type `xxd ttt`, and paste the output here.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.
with just the first line and its name changed to ttt, I get no errors
and the output of xxd is:

0000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 68              #!/bin/bash

Comment: maybe, I am creating the file in notepad++ in Windows

Comment: but I still get and error stating that it cannot open the second filefor reading. It reads from file1 and writes file2 or allthe way around ? reads from file2 and write file1 ?

Comment: What are the names of your input files?

Comment: to avoid extended discussions in comments, I will put another question based on your script, but with the correct files and parameters that I will use. Thank you

Comment: I see. going to test again

Comment: I think this kind of discussion is ok in the comments, so we may continue the discussion if you like also..

Comment: Ok, the scrit works like a charm. Thank you, just another issue, if I wanted to create a file with the results what do I have to place instead of print ?

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out.. To save the output to a file, you just redirect the output of the `awk` program to, say, `file3`. So the last line of the script would then change to: `}' file1 file2 > file3`